# echo javascript from php not working?

Tags: php, javascript, html, echo

So, in an html page I'm trying to have a php segment echo some javascript code, as seen here:

```
<?php
    echo "This was legitimately hit";
    if(!empty($_POST['name']))
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("We got the name");</script>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("We DID NOT get the name");</script>';
    }
?>
```

and from what I've read online, this seems to be a legitimate way of doing things, but the page seems to be reading the first part up until the first closing chevron (seen just below here) as a comment.

```
<?php
    echo "This was legitimately hit";
    if(!empty($_POST['name']))
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
```

Then it reads the else and next echo as plain text, and puts it on the webpage. the next javascript code block then gets read as a regular javascript code block, so the page does a pop-up saying it did not get the name. The closing bracket and closing chevron then just get output as more text.

So in the end the page just ends up having

```
alert("We got the name")'; } else { echo ''; } ?>
```

printed on it as plain text, and has a pop-up that says we received no name.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: I don't think this is the real code except you are writing the code in an environment where html tags are not allowed - like in Content Management System html editor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like the file isn't being processed as PHP. Does the file name end in .php? Are you sure PHP is installed and hooked up correctly to the web server?

edit: To handle the Facebook requests in the same page:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['facebook_request_field'])) {
  // handle the Facebook request, output any necessary response
  // then exit
  exit;
}

?>
<!-- display the web page normally here -->
```

So for your test page:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("got a name!");</script>';
  exit;
}

?>
<script type="text/javascript">alert("No name.");</script>
```

(That's actually identical in function to what you already have, so maybe I'm misunderstanding the purpose.)

Comment: Well this is all in an html page.

Comment: php will not execute in an html page.  It needs to "be" a php page (file extension of php, not html) for the php code to be processed.

Comment: Servers can be set up to process .html pages as php. @Zahel: see if any php at all runs correctly before troubleshooting the javascript.

Comment: @ScottSaunders, it runs a regular php just fine.

Comment: By "regular php," do you mean a file ending in .php?

Comment: @CMKanode, ok, so this code block runs perfectly well in it's own php file. So, since my webpage is inside of index.html, and it will handle all messages sent to this directory, how would I make it forward all the POSTs to a seperate php file?

Comment: @Dan, yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having an index.php file, as long as the server is set up to recognize that (in Apache, the `DirectoryIndex index.php` directive). An HTML file won't be able to recognize POST requests and handle them, they can only serve up straight HTML.

Comment: So, setting it as the index.php is just fine, but how then do I get it to load the desired page? (Yes, I'm painfully new to this stuff, sorry for this)

Comment: We'll need some more details as to the purpose of the script, right now you're just taking a name from a form and celebrating that with a JavaScript alert.

Comment: Ok, well this is some stuff I'm trying to get working for a facebook game, and it's hosted inside of a "canvas" on one of their app pages. The address for the canvas page has to be an index (something.com/index/), but they also send a signed request to that page in a POST message. so I need  that index to handle a POST message, to where I can retrieve the data from it, but I also need it to load a webpage.

Comment: Well, using a header seemed to work pretty well. I don't get the pop-up, but I'm using it in such a place that it could't redirect should it not be getting hit. ( header ("location: http://something.com/index/game.html"); )

Comment: It's hard to explain down here in the comments, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Why use isset instead of just checking the variable itself?

Comment: If nothing's being posted to the page, $_POST will be empty, and $_POST['name'] won't exist. `isset()` checks to see if the variable exists. `empty()` should be used on variables that exist, but that you want to check as empty, i.e. an empty array or an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Between `We got the signed request` and `We got the name`, I think you haven't given us the actual code that's causing the error. Double check that, and make sure you don't have any stray single quotes before your `alert` call.

Comment: How do you explain the different strings?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, the "signed request" was bit was not supposed to be there, it was supposed to be "the name". All the code here is referring to the same code, I just overwrote something by accident.

Answer (score 0):

There are missing `;` after the `alert`. Have you tried correcting this first?

Comment: just tried this, changed nothing. Will change the initial post to reflect this.

Comment: that should not stop php from printing the string

Comment: it also wouldn't stop the javascript from running